# Physical disk rewrite of mysql data

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql for the first time in years to help a friend out.  The issue:  a mysql table that gets updated a lot with INT and CHAR values. This web app site is hosted on a large generic provider, so I have no direct control of setup/parameters/etc.  The performance has gotten really, really bad for this table, to the point where processing a data page that should take a max of 10 seconds is sometimes taking 15 minutes.

I initially tried running all updates as a single transaction, rather than the 50ish statements in a php loop in the web app (written several years ago).  The problem, at least what I think, is that this app is running on a giant mysql instance with many other generic websites, and the disk speed just isn't able to handle so many updates.

I am able to use chron/batch jobs on this provider.  The web app is mainly used during work hours, so I could limit access to the web app during overnight hours.

I normally work with postgresql or ms sql server, so my knowledge of mysql is fairly limited.

Would performance be increased if I force the table to be dropped and rewritten overnight?  Is there some mysql function like postgres's vacuum?  I have tried to search for information, but unfortunately using words like rewrite table just brings up references to sql syntax helpers or performance tuning.

Alternately, I guess that I could create a new storage mechanism in mysql, as long as it could be done via a php script.  Would there be a better storage mode than the default storage engine for something frequently updated?

Comment: Can you provide more information on your database engine and schema?

Comment: It is whatever a default mysql install would include, I don't know the verison offhand.  In terms of schema, this is a simple table with a primary key and six data columns.  One char and one int column's values are updated during a manufacturing process many times.

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner.pl (perl) report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Comment: MySQL's OPTIMIZE could be thought of as similar to postgres's vacuum - in that it will eliminate fragmentation of a table and clean up indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Performance of `mysql` depends on multiple factors that it's complicated enough to have a clear answer in every case. I think we can check the following steps to help figuring out on what to improve on `INSERT` data into `mysql`.

### Database Engine.

There are 5 engine that you can use depends on your purposes: MyISAM, Memory, InnoDB, Archive, NDB.

[Document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-engines.html)

- An engine which has `Locking granularity` as `table` will be slower than engine has its value as `row` because it will lock a table from changing when insert or update a single record, while `Locking granularity` as `row` mean locking only that row when you insert or update records.
- When perform `INSERT` OR `UPDATE` record, engine has `B-tree indexes` attribute will be slower because it's have to rebuild it's indexes, so that you will have faster speed `SELECT` query. Therefore number of indexes in table will slow inserting and updating speed as well.
- Indexes as `CHAR` will be slower than indexes as `INT` because it takes more time to figure out where to find the right node to store data in `mysql`.

### MYSQL Statement

MYSQL has a estimation system that help you to discover performance of a query by add `EXPLAIN` before your `mysql` statement.

**Example**

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM Table_A WHERE id = 1;
```

[Document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-extended.html)

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a web application, where we used mysql (it's really good !) to scale really large data.

In addition to what @Lam Nguyen said in his answer here is few things to consider,

1. Check which mysql engine you are using to see which locks it obtains during `select`, `insert` , `update`. To check which engine you are using here is a sample query with which you could run your litmus test.

```html
mysql> show table status where name="<your_table_name>";
+-------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name  | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation          | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+-------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Login | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    |    2 |           8192 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |           NULL | 2019-04-28 12:16:59 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_general_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+-------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
```

The default engine which comes with mysql installation is `InnoDB`. InnoDB does not acquire any lock while inserting a row.

- SELECT ... FROM is a consistent read, reading a snapshot of the database and setting no locks unless the transaction isolation level is set to SERIALIZABLE.
- A locking read, an UPDATE, or a DELETE generally set record locks on every index record that is scanned in the processing of the SQL statement.

[InnoDB lock sets](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html)

2. Check for columns which you are indexing. Index the column which you would really query a lot. Avoid indexing char columns.

To check which columns of you table got indexed run,

```html
mysql> show index from BookStore2;
+------------+------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name       | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+------------+------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Bookstore2 |          0 | PRIMARY        |            1 | ISBN_NO     | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Bookstore2 |          1 | SHORT_DESC_IND |            1 | SHORT_DESC  | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Bookstore2 |          1 | SHORT_DESC_IND |            2 | PUBLISHER   | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+------------+------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

3. Do not run inner query on a large data set in a table. To actually see what your query does run `explain` on your query and see the number of rows iter

```html
mysql> explain select * from login;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | login | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    2 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.03 sec)
```

4. Avoid joining too may tables.
5. Make sure you are querying with a primary key in criteria or at least you are querying on your indexed column.
6. When your table grows too big make sure you split it across clusters.

With few tweaks, we would still be able to get query results in minimal time.